# How to deduce array type in template?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

I'm writing some simple template returning an array which would be a product of multiplication of values of two arrays sent by parameters.
How can I deduce the type of array that I want to return?

For simplicity I've specified size of both arrays because I'm only curious how to declare that third array.

I could only do it like this:

```
template <typename T, typename S>
S *New_Array(T *tab, S *tab2){

   static double tab3[5]{};       

   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i ++){
      *(tab3 + i) = *(tab +i) * *(tab2 + i);
   }

   return tab3;
}
```

but this kind of template is not very usefull...

I thought that maybe I should have used something like:

```
template <typename T, typename S>
auto New_Array(T *tab, S *tab2) -> decltype(*tab * *tab2){}
```

but I guess it only gives me return in form of (in this case) double, am I correct?

Also, the same problem with declaring new array occures in main where I want to assign a return value from function template.
So I tried to use decltype:

```
int tab[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
double tab2[] = {1.5, 2.3, 3.6, 7.8, 9.0};

typedef decltype(*tab * *tab2) MYARR;
MYARR tab3[5]{};
```

but it didn't work as I tought it would and now I'm stuck with my horrible template without any idea how to move on.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend against using raw arrays.  They can't be returned by value so you have to either use a static local variable or use dynamic memory allocation to get a pointer to an array.

Instead you can use `std::array`, which is like a raw array, but it is a lot easier to use.  If you use that then your function can become

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, std::size_t N>
auto New_Array(const std::array<T1, N>& tab, const std::array<T2, N>& tab2)
{
   std::array<decltype(std::declval<T1&>() * std::declval<T2&>()), N> res;

   for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i){
      res[i] = tab[i] * tab2[i];
   }
   return res;
}
```

Comment: But I won't use `common_type` but `decltype (tab[0] * tab2[0])` anyway ;-)

Comment: @Jarod42 Yeah, the more I look at it the more I think that it could be wrong when proxy types are used.  I'll do the same thing but differently ;)

Comment: Thanks to both of you, that is what I was looking for. I will need to read more about std::array and then study your solutions because I wasn't using it earlier.

Answer (score 1):

C-array has lot of limitation as you cannot return them, better and easier to use `std::array` instead.

Then you might do thing such as:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, std::size_t N>
auto
New_Array(const std::array<T1, N>& tab, const std::array<T2, N>& tab2)
-> std::array<std::decay_t<decltype(tab[0] * tab2[0])>, N>
{
   std::array<std::decay_t<decltype(tab[0] * tab2[0])>, N> res;

   for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i){
      res[i] = tab[i] * tab2[i];
   }
   return res;
}
```

With usage

```
std::array<int, 5> tab{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}};
std::array<double, 5> tab2{{1.5, 2.3, 3.6, 7.8, 9.0}};

auto tab3 = New_Array(tab, tab2); // auto is std::array<double, 5>
```